# In Place editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I followed all the steps according to http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast

but it is not editing at the attributes place?

This is my page

```
<div class="well-lg box-left box-first">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>Personal Details</h3>
    <br>
    <ul class="list-group">
    <li><strong><div class="col-sm-4">FName </div></strong>
      <%= best_in_place @user, :fname %></li>
    <li><strong><div class="col-sm-4">LName </div></strong>
      <%=  best_in_place @user, :lname %></li>
    <li><strong><div class="col-sm-4">Email </div></strong>
      <%=  best_in_place @user, :email %></li>
    <li><strong><div class="col-sm-4">Mobile </div></strong>
      <%=  best_in_place @user, :mob %></li>
    </ul><br><%= link_to 'Edit', {:controller=>'users', :action=>'edit'}%>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or solution??
Thanks in advance

Edit

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

user.js.coffee

```
 jQuery ->
 $('.best_in_place').best_in_place();
```

Comment: Have you set up the jQuery code? `$('.best_in_place').best_in_place()`

Comment: Have you configured your routes properly?

Comment: Do we have to specify any routes for best_in_place gem @Bhanu

Comment: I think you are using Rails 4, best_in_place is not completely compatible with Rails 4 yet. Check that once.

Comment: Yes am using Rails 4..any solution?? @Aakash

Comment: best_in_place DOES support rails 4, and it is actively maintained since seuros started to maintain it. Also, I am using it on rails 4

Comment: any solution why its not working then @Nick

Comment: show your controller code and JS if any

Comment: **As a option** you can also try [Xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) jQuery version. It works for me

Comment: How to use Xeditable @Abhi

Comment: @KratiPillai Checkout the [documentation](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html), its very easy. And I'm using the **jQuery UI** version of it

Comment: Can you put this in answer in a step by process @Abhi

Answer (score 1):

`Best_in_place` is not completely compatible with `Rails 4`, you can try the following gems and see if they work.

https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/bootstrap-editable-rails

https://github.com/janv/rest_in_place

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to put just the helper in the HTML

you need to have the proper code in the controller as well

your controller code should look like this (the json responses)

```
def update
  @user = User.find params[:id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
    end
  end
end
```

as for the helper, not sure if it does this by default, try adding `as: :input`

see here https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place

Answer (score 0):

Although, everything is clear and step by step in [documentation](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html), but as per your request, following is the way I'm using it:

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery-editable
```

**application.css**

```
*= require jquery-editable
```

**view**

```
<a href="javscript:void(0)" id="some_id">
```

**javascript**

```
jQuery.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
jQuery.fn.editable.defaults.ajaxOptions = {type: "PUT"};

jQuery("#some_id").editable({
  type: "text",
  pk: "1",  //This is id of the record which will be updated
  url: url  //The rails URL for controller method
});
```

**Still, I recommend you to go through the documentation for better understanding and smoother implementation.**